# How to resolve trace_filter does not exist when deploying balancer sub-graph in graph-node?

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

I've setup [graph-node](https://github.com/graphprotocol/graph-node) successfully. After that, I was trying to deploy [balancer-subgraph](https://github.com/balancer-labs/balancer-subgraph) in my graph-node.

Sub-graph deployment procedure:

1. clone

```
git clone git@github.com:balancer-labs/balancer-subgraph.git
```

2. Install dependencies

```
yarn
```

3. Generate the graph code

```
yarn codegen
```

4. Create local node

```
yarn create:local
```

5. Deploy locally

```
yarn deploy:local
```

After deploying I'm getting error like below in my graph node logs

```
Aug 21 13:15:36.545 ERRO Subgraph instance failed to run: RPC error: Error { code: MethodNotFound, message: "the method trace_filter does not exist/is not available", data: None }, code: SubgraphSyncingFailure, id: QmTMsUH9rUVjpBTDRNuUcNHM3rT9ZZmxkDmTYmyKUpzEJn, subgraph_id: QmTMsUH9rUVjpBTDRNuUcNHM3rT9ZZmxkDmTYmyKUpzEJn, component: SubgraphInstanceManager
Aug 21 13:15:41.071 INFO Syncing 1 blocks from Ethereum., code: BlockIngestionStatus, blocks_needed: 1, blocks_behind: 1, latest_block_head: 10703787, current_block_head: 10703786, network_name: mainnet,
component: BlockIngestor
```

get node version

```
Geth
Version: 1.9.9-stable
Git Commit: 017449971e1e9e220efcd97d3313a0e27f47003b
Git Commit Date: 20191206
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [64 63]
Go Version: go1.13.5
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=/home/ubuntu/work
GOROOT=/usr/local/go
```

Do I need to enable any kind of API to successfully deploy balancer subgraph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Geth node doesn't have support `trace_filter` method so far. For some subgraph like balancer-subgraph, when try to deploy it to `graph-node`, it'll try to call this method `trace_filter`. but as geth node didn't have API support, graph-node faces error for this

Reference: Geth JSON-RPC doesn't have `trace_filter` API support.
Follow [this](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/server) link to find the supported APIs by geth node.

To fully support graph-node need to use parity node. [This](https://openethereum.github.io/wiki/JSONRPC-trace-module#trace_filter) has supported APIs by parity